# Delete specified record from MS Access table using java database connection

Tags: java, database-connection, ms-access-2013

I am trying to update or delete a single particular record from table, say
("UPDATE studentTable set Name ='Shekhar' WHERE 'Roll Number = 116'");
I should get only that record where roll number is 116 updated to Name "Shekhar" but instead I am getting all records updated with Name "Shekhar".
Same thing happens with Delete statement and all records are deleted where it should be that particular record.
I feel like it's a syntax error as the sql statement is only reading update or delete statement but ignore the WHERE clause. I have tried putting 'inverted comma' at different places but then I got syntax error saying operator missing..
Name of table is "studentTable", roll number is primary key
data source name is student.
Here is the exact code.. Please tell me how should I correct the code as per requirement.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StudentDbConnect
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection connectDb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:student");
        Statement view = connectDb.createStatement();
        //view.executeUpdate("INSERT into studentTable values('Tauqeer','116','FET','CSE')");
        //view.executeUpdate("INSERT into studentTable values('Tauqeer2','117','FET','CSE')");
        //view.executeUpdate("INSERT into studentTable values('Tauqeer3','118','FET','CSE')");
        //view.executeUpdate("INSERT into studentTable values('Tauqeer4','119','FET','CSE')");
        //view.executeUpdate("INSERT into studentTable values('Tauqeer5','120','FET','CSE')");
        //view.executeUpdate("UPDATE studentTable set Name ='Shekhar' WHERE 'Roll Number = 116'");
        //view.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM studentTable WHERE 'Roll Number = 116'");
        view.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM studentTable");
        ResultSet result = view.getResultSet();

        while(result.next())
        {
            System.out.println("Name = " +result.getString(1) + " Roll Number = " +result.getInt(2)+" Department = " +result.getString(3)+" Branch = "+result.getString(4));
        }
        view.close();
        connectDb.close();
    }
    catch(Exception raisedException)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception " +raisedException);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE clause

```sql
... WHERE 'Roll Number = 116'
```

is malformed. If `Roll Number` is a text column then it should be

```sql
... WHERE [Roll Number] = '116'
```

If `Roll Number` is a numeric column then it should be

```sql
... WHERE [Roll Number] = 116
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but `view.executeUpdate("UPDATE studentTable set Name ='Shekhar' WHERE [Roll Number] = '116'");` This creates _Exception java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression._ Can you take a look at entire statement line?

Comment: If [Roll Number] is actually a numeric column (despite what your INSERT statements suggest) then you need to remove the single quotes around the value: `... WHERE [Roll Number] = 116`.

Comment: Thank you!!.. I was also wondering why it gave data type mismatch .. I have just begun database . I will be careful of such silly mistakes.